# loading many comma deliminated files in a folder on HDFS into pyspark dataframe first file has header

Tags: pyspark

I have a folder in HDFS. The contents of the folder are:

```
_SUCCESS
part-00000
part-00001
...
part-00048
```

These files are in csv format. The first file `part-00000` has the header. The rest of the files don't.

When I read the file, I use this command:

```
spark.read.load(
        fileLocation, 
        format='com.databricks.spark.csv', 
        header='true', 
        inferSchema='true'
    )
```

When I load, I get a warning: `WARN  CSVDataSource:66 - CSV header does not conform to the schema.`

This error is appearing when reading all of the files except the first, as the first contains the header

Full error:

```
WARN  CSVDataSource:66 - CSV header does not conform to the schema.
 Header: <row of data>
 Schema: <header field names>
Expected: <header field names>
```

Above, basically, it says that the file header was the first row of data of the file. But it expected the header. So I think this is because only the first file has the header. `HDFS getmerge` handles this fine. How can I avoid this error when loading the file as csv with python / pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the first file in a separate dataframe to get its schema, then apply that schema to the rest of the files

```py
sample = spark.read.load(
        'part-00000', 
        format='com.databricks.spark.csv', 
        header=True, 
        inferSchema=True,
    )

df = spark.read.load(
        fileLocation,
        format='com.databricks.spark.csv', 
        schema=sample.schema
    )
```